# Launching word with javascript without ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, activex, client-server, system.diagnostics

I am developing a content management system in asp.net where the users of the system will use it to submit their work as well as open their previous/unfinished work (writing) in Microsoft Word 2003. Now the problem is if I use C# System.Diagnostics library it works perfectly if the system is deployed on local server (i.e the PC on which I am developing) but I think if I deploy it on another PC and run it on a client PC using LAN connection it will launch word on PC acting as server instead of client although I haven't tried this but this is what I doubt, is there any way I can launch word on client machine using Javascript but without using ActiveX as it restrict the user to use IE only while our users choose their own browser ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Browser scripting cannot interact with the client machine, period, unless you have some plugins installed that would allow it.

Microsoft, and its ActiveX, are an exception, where they break the rules so they can improve integration with their operating system. Many people think it's another of Microsoft's blunders, since it is often viewed as a big security risk.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I think you're right. More people will exploit this feature then using it for good work. I have to change my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, and for good reason too. Could you imagine if any website were allowed to run executables on client computers...?

Comment: Ok I think I should stop focusing on that, but can I use Silverlight instead to launch client side application such that I will use asp.net and silverlight interop to provide silverlight the necessary information such as filename that is available on server to launch it on client side application ?

Comment: Silverlight also has limited access to client machine as it works in isolated storage, hmm not good for my project but at least I am learning things this way. Thanks for your answer.